# React native drawer font Color

Tags: react-native, colors, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, react-navigation-drawer

My code:

```
 return (
 
<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeTabs"  

drawerContent={props => {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem activeTinTcolor = 'red' inactiveTintColor='red' label="Logout" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Login")} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
   )
  }}
  >
<Drawer.Screen  name="HomeTabs" initialParams={{userId: userId, name: name, url: url,fullName: fullName, password: password}} component={HomeTabs} />
<Drawer.Screen name="Authors" component={AuthorsScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>

);
 }
```

In DrawerItem I can change the color of the text but when I want to do so in Drawer.Screen none of the options work. I try options, DrowerOptions and and none of them work.

[image: Drawer View]

Answer (score 0):

you can add it in screenOptions like below

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  initialRouteName="HomeTabs"
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
    drawerActiveTintColor:"red",
    drawerInactiveTintColor:"orange"
  }}
  drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerMenu {...props} />}
>
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

[more options](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#options)